# Web-mode uses 1 space indent instead of 2

Tags: web-mode, html, javascript

I have this config in my init.el:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html?\\'" . web-mode))
(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  "Hooks for Web mode."
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 4)
  (setq web-mode-enable-auto-pairing t)
  (setq web-mode-enable-auto-closing t)
  (setq web-mode-enable-current-element-highlight t)
  (setq web-mode-enable-current-column-highlight t)
)
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'my-web-mode-hook)
```

And when I have script tag I only have javascript code indented by 1 space instead of 2. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `(setq web-mode-script-padding 2)`.

You should also call `my-web-mode-hook` only once, after you first load `web-mode` and not every time the mode is activated:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'web-mode
  (my-web-mode-hook))
```

Comment: Greetings from 2022, you saved my day